# Odoo/OpenERP: hiding create button from treeview

Tags: python, treeview, odoo, openerp-7

I have a situation here. I am using OpenERP 7. I am trying to hide Create button from tree view of my products. this can be done using

```
<tree create="false" .....
```

but situation is like. i want to keep it when user opens the tree view directly from "Asset Management" Module. But hide it when i click on Reporting for treeview.

I tried to use context like this from reporting button's function:

```
context['prod1']='false'
ctx = dict(context)
print ctx['prod1']

return {
   'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
   'res_model': 'product.product',
   'view_type': 'form',
   'view_mode': 'tree,form',
   'target': 'current',
   'context':ctx,
   'create':False,   
   'domain':[('id','in',domain)]
}
```

and in treeview form I did:

```
<tree create="context.get('prod1',False)"
```

but I get this json related error:

```
ERROR : SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

this stuff is working with my button but not with my tree view. I tried adding `'create':False` in return too, but unable to do what I want to. What am I missing?

Comment: Same question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25376304/disable-create-and-discard-button-for-specific-function-in-openerp

Comment: Question is same. But answer?? nowhere :(

Comment: in that case why not define different tree view for both menus, and use create="false" in the one where you don't want to see button.

Answer (score 2):

Are the views your accessing the same or are they different ?

If they are different, I believe the proper way to implement your requirement is to override the relevant view with the

`create="false"`

property you mentioned.

From the technical memento:

> #### View Inheritance
>
> Existing views should be modifying through inherited views, never directly. An inherited view references its parent view using the inherit_id field, and may add or modify existing elements in the view by referencing them through XPath expressions, and specifying the appropriate position.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Here, Keep in mind, create="false" is only correct where create="False" will not work, its because odoo bullshit development.

Comment: i see all similar posts say to add a create="false" but it totally didn't work for me...

Answer (score 2):

I successfully solved the very same issue by using field_view_get:

```
def fields_view_get(self, cr, uid, view_id=None, view_type='form', context=None, toolbar=False, submenu=False):
    res = models.Model.fields_view_get(self, cr, uid, view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type, context=context, toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu)
    default_type = context.get('default_type', False)
    can_create = default_type != 'out_customer_production'
    update = not can_create and view_type in ['form', 'tree']
    if update:
        doc = etree.XML(res['arch'])
        if not can_create:
            for t in doc.xpath("//"+view_type):
                t.attrib['create'] = 'false'
        res['arch'] = etree.tostring(doc)

    return res
```

(I left tree and form view without the create attribute)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how to do it in python + xml either, i would stick with javascript extension, that gets data from context or from fields and disable and hide button depending on that data.