# Enable options field inherit in Odoo 8

Tags: xml, inheritance, conditional-statements, odoo, openerp-8

I have a field inherit, and I want add an attribute, but conditional. Options no_create if is a group X. Any similar to:

```
<field name="state_id" position="attributes">                       
    <attribute name="options">{'no_create': [('groups', '==', 'X')]}</attribute>
</field>
```

I tried different ways (==, =), but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this.

[hiding create button from treeview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25379647/odoo-openerp-hiding-create-button-from-treeview/32904951#32904951)

You can change the snippet I gave into my answer in order to check the group of the user instead of tha parameter inside the context

Comment: Thanks Alessandro, finally can dispense with other solution.